# Python script where multiple excel files with multiple sheets in them are merged into one excel file but with separate sheets

Tags: python, excel

I have 2 excel files having single sheets. I want to merge them into one excel containing two worksheets(one from each of those excel). I have a hyperlink in one of the column of sheet1. While merging those excels, the hyperlink columns is not getting populated and I am seeing N/A for values in that hyperlink column

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

location = 'C:\\Users\\*.xls'
excel_files = glob.glob(location)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\merged_sheets.xlsx')

for excel_file in excel_files:
    sheet = os.path.basename(excel_file)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df1.fillna(value='N/A', inplace=True)
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)

writer.save()
```